# Pandas GroupBy Join Strings Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Could somebody tell me how to simplify this piece of code? It is archaic to write all the column names, specially on wide tables. For some reason if I run `df.groupby('APID').agg(','.join)` it does not return all the columns. Only the first 3. All the columns are of type `'object'`.

```
df.groupby('APID').agg(
    {'Names':','.join,
     'Alias_Name':','.join,
     'APID':','.join,
     'Prev_Rep':','.join,
     'Rep_Assigned':','.join,
     'City':','.join,
     'State':','.join,
     'Zip_Code':','.join,
     'Country':','.join,
     'Distribution_Numbers':','.join,
     'Partnership':','.join,
     'Onboarding':','.join,}
)
```

Comment: Try `df.groupby('APID').apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))` or `df.groupby('APID').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))`

Comment: This `df.groupby('APID').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))` worked beautifully. Thanks pal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just this:

```
df.groupby('APID').apply(','.join)
```